# ZF2 testing - mock object ignored by serviceManager

Tags: testing, zend-framework2, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to run tests on my controller in Zend Framework 2.3.

My tested action looks like this:

```
public function listAction() {

        // optional filtering
        $filter = $this->params('filter'); // filter type

        // params from JSON
        $jsonPost = $this->getRequest()->getContent();
        $params = json_decode($jsonPost);
        $param1 = isset($params->query1) ? $params->query1 : NULL;
        $param2 = isset($params->query2) ? $params->query2 : NULL;

        $json = Array( // json container
            'status' => TRUE,
            'data' => Array(),
            ); 

        try {

            // get data from Model
            $list = new Mapping\Books\Listing();

            if( !empty($filter)) { // optional filtering
                $list->addFilter($filter, $param1, $param2);
            }

            $data = $list->setOrder()->getList();

            // final data mapping to JSON and formating
            foreach($data as $isbn => $book) {
                $json['data'][$isbn] = Array(
                    'ISBN' => $book->getISBN(),
                    'title' => $book->getTitle(),
                    'rating' => $book->getRating(),
                    'release_date' => $book->getReleaseDate()->format('F Y'),
                    'authors' => Array() // multiple
                );

                // final authors mapping
                foreach($book->getAuthors() as $author) {
                    $json['data'][$isbn]['authors'][] = Array(
                        'author_id' => $author->getId(),
                        'author_name' => $author->getName()
                    );
                }
            }

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $json = Array(
                'status' => FALSE,
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            );        
        }

        return new JsonModel( $json );

    }
```

My testing method looks like this:

```
public function testListActionWithoutParams()
    {

        // object mocking
        $listingMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Books\Model\Mapping\Books\Listing')
                        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                        ->setMethods(Array('getData', 'setOrder'))
                        ->getMock();


        $listingMock->expects($this->once())->method('setOrder')
                    ->will($this->returnSelf());

        $listingMock->expects($this->once())->method('getData')
                    ->willReturn( Array() ); // for testing is enough

        $serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
        $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
        $serviceManager->setService('Books\Model\Mapping\Books\Listing', $listingMock);

        // dispatch
        $this->dispatch('/books');

        // routing tests
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->assertModuleName('Books');
        $this->assertControllerName('Books\Controller\Index');
        $this->assertControllerClass('IndexController');
        $this->assertActionName('list');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('list');

        // header tests
        $this->assertResponseHeaderContains('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

}
```

I think I'm missunderstanding something here. My understanding is, that serviceManager will also "notify" autoloader, that actually called class should be replaced by mock object, but it does not.

How can I replace my object with mocked, please ?

Comment: You must inject mocked class to object. E.g. using DI.

Comment: could you please provide how to achieve this on the situation above ? I'm playing with Service manager right now, but still no luck to get that replaced, even in special cases, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you controller have a lot of logic, what is incorrect.

Secondly, I can give you only workflow of the code:

In your controller you need a method with will be returning list object, so in line:

```
// get data from Model
$list = new Mapping\Books\Listing();
```

should be new method call:

```
// get data from Model
$list = $this->getListing();
```

And the method:

```
public function getListing()
{
    return new Mapping\Books\Listing();
}
```

Now you need to mock this method in the controller. And object returned by the mocked method should be your mocked `Mapping\Books\Listing` object.

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I did it, lets say, similar way, by using Factory object providing Listing class and passing it by SM. So lets say I can accept your answer :)

Comment: btw, the logic in Controller is not "real" logic - just formatting of JSON output. I think it's better to have final formatting in the controller, instead of has it hardcoded in the DB service :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but when you use factory then you can return mocked `Listing` too.

Comment: About btw, there should be special class, some helper etc which will be formatting output. Controller is responsible only to get request form client and put it forward.